# Bash: use nth row as part of the command line

Tags: bash, shell, loops, unix, tail

I am trying to use a tool called fastqtl, but it's probably less relevant here. I am interested in assigning each row of the "loc_info.txt" into the options. I wrote the following commands but it bounced back as "Error parsing command line :unrecognised option '-n+1'

Is there a way that I can make the fastQTL read and use that 1 line from "loc_info.txt" each time it runs the function?

Thanks for any suggestions!!

```
#!/bin/bash

tool="/path/FastQTL-2.165.linux/bin/"
vcf="/path/vcf/"
out="/path/perm_out"

for i in {1..1061}
do
${tool}fastQTL.1.165.linux --vcf ${vcf}GT.vcf.gz --bed pheno_bed.gz --region tail -n+"$i" loc_info.txt --permute 1000 --out "$i"_perm.txt
done
```

Comment: you should take a look at `xargs`. let me write it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subshell for this, if you want to use the output from one command within another command so something like:

```
cmd1 -option $(cmd2)
```

here you're using the cmd2 output as input in cmd. The key here is '$' and the subshell '()'. So the solution might be:

```
#!/bin/bash
tool="/path/FastQTL-2.165.linux/bin/"
vcf="/path/vcf/"
out="/path/perm_out"

for i in {1..1061}
do
${tool}fastQTL.1.165.linux --vcf ${vcf}GT.vcf.gz --bed pheno_bed.gz --region $(tail -n+"$i" loc_info.txt) --permute 1000 --out "$i"_perm.txt
done
```

Comment: No problem! I'm glad I could help you

Answer (score 3):

Read the file in a loop:

```
i=1
while read -r line; do
    ${tool}fastQTL.1.165.linux --vcf ${vcf}GT.vcf.gz --bed pheno_bed.gz --region "$line" --permute 1000 --out "$i"_perm.txt
    ((i++))
done < loc_info.txt
```

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, I love this method! It's working very well and easy to understand as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `tail -n+"$i" loc_info.txt`
    with `$(head -n $i loc_info.txt | tail -n 1)`

**Example**

```
numOfLines=$(wc -l loc_info.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1)

for i in $(seq 1 $numOfLines) 
do
${tool}fastQTL.1.165.linux --vcf ${vcf}GT.vcf.gz --bed pheno_bed.gz -
-region $(head -n $i loc_info.txt | tail -n 1) --permute 1000 --out "$i"_perm.txt
done
```

Comment: `sed -n ${N}p` is a cleaner way to print line $N than `head | tail`